# ERROR with Gradle build in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Every time I load a project I get the following errors, and I have tried everything that I have found on the internet to resolve these errors such as

1. Deleting .gradle file in users folder and letting android build it again.
2. I have tried the re validating cache and restarting it.
3. Re downloading Android Studio after uninstalling previous version.

I have tried numerous anwsers that have helped a lot of people, but it still does not work for me.Basically it's all my dependices. Yesterday i opened a friends project to put it on his kindle to demo for the lecturer but all it did was destroy my android studio. can anyone help please?

> Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1
>   Install Repository and sync projectShow in File
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:(24, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
>   Install Repository and sync project
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:(24, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
>   Install Repository and sync project 
>   Show in Project Structure dialog

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
     }
     buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: put your gradle file here

Comment: ok i will there now

Comment: i think the problem is with your android support / google repositories 
try updating them and see if that helps

Comment: you see the gradle will not sync at all, gives giving m all dependices errors and it wont let me click it to install Repository

Comment: update them from sdk manager

Comment: i have tried all this but thank you

Comment: try changing your `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`..

Comment: i have tried this but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the support repository, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html):

1. Start the Android SDK Manager.
2. In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list, find the Extras folder and, if necessary, expand to show its contents.
3. Select the Android Support Repository item.
4. Click the Install packages... button.

Comment: there is actually no extras folder i just checked

Comment: What is your version of the "Android Support Repository"?

Comment: Google repository 46, and support Repository is 47.0.0

Comment: But in Android Studio, the "Install Repository" part of the error message is a link, isn't it? Did you click on it?

Comment: Yeah i did, i showed my lecturer and he said. It would be a big job to rectify. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Can you explain what happened when you clicked on "Install Repository"?

Comment: nothing happened it just stayed on the same screen, i tried it on a computer in college and it worked fine. its strange.